# How to test my Ruby on Rails website against brute force properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, brute-force

I placed a honeypot captcha on my website and I wanted to test it against a brute force attack.  So I run Hydra brute force tool using a password list with my actual password in it.  Hydra doesn't end up finding the password on my site.
I try Medusa and Ncrack and they don't seem to work well either.  I noticed that these programs seem to want a file extension such as www.website.com/login.php instead of just a www.website.com/login directory.  Does Rails actually serve an extension in the url?  .html, .rb, or anything like that?
This seems like a good thing to me but I know that there is something out there that can run a brute force.  I am curious as to how my login page will hold up since I am not running Devise to restrict login attempts.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just calculate how many guesses it takes on average to find the matching username/password set and multiple it with your application's average response time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar testing with webkit like rspec, selenium, capybara, here is example of my simple thought :

```
scenario 'test brute force' do
  usernames = File.readlines('data/usernames.txt')
  passwords = File.readlines('data/passwords.txt')

  usernames.each do |username|
    passwords.each do |password|
      visit customer_login_path
      fill_in('Username', with: username.gsub(/\n|\r/,''))
      fill_in('Password', with: password.gsub(/\n|\r/,''))
      click_button('Login')
      expect(page).to have_css('.alert.in.alert-danger', text: 'Username or password is invalid')
    end
  end
end
```